# ScheduledExecutorService schedule not triggering

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

The following code block does not work for me (alert is not being triggered):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ParseException {        
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(Thread::new);
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("The time now is: " + calendar.getTime());
    System.out.println("Enter alert date time: ");
    String dateStr = scanner.nextLine();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    Date date = sdf.parse(dateStr);
    calendar.setTime(date);
    long alertTimeInMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    long now = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone).getTimeInMillis();
    System.out.println("Time to alert: " + (alertTimeInMillis - now) + " millis ");

    ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutorService.schedule(() -> System.out.println("alert!")
            , alertTimeInMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    
    while (!scheduledFuture.isDone()) {
        System.out.println("The time now: " + Calendar.getInstance(timeZone).getTime());
        System.out.println("Expected alert time: " + date);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
    scheduledExecutorService.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

While this code block does work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(Thread::new);
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2023, 1, 10, 12, 1);
    ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutorService.schedule(() ->
            System.out.println("alert!"),
            LocalDateTime.now().until(localDateTime, ChronoUnit.SECONDS), TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    while (!scheduledFuture.isDone()) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
    scheduledExecutorService.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

I don't understand the difference, or what exactly is wrong with the first block that I'm missing.

Comment: You seem to have a misconception in the first snippet: you print `(alertTimeInMillis - now)` as the time to alert but only pass `alertTimeInMillis` to `schedule(...)`. If you read the JavaDoc on `Calendar.getTimeInMillis()` you'll see that this is the number of milliseconds since epoch (i.e. 1/1/1970 00:00:00,000 UTC) and if you delay by that amount of millis you'd wait another 53 years for the alert :) - Btw, the second snippet is better anyway as it ditches the old `java.util.Date` API.

Comment: I understand, thanks ! The reason I use the old `Date` is because I'm trying to help someone with an exercise which requires them to work with it (unfortunately:).

Comment: That is indeed very unfortunate. No one should learn to use the troublesome and long outdated `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `TimZone` classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Debugging legacy code

> `ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(Thread::new);`

No need for that `Thread::new`. Use empty parens, no arguments needed.

> `TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());`

Weird. You are mixing the legacy `TimeZone` class with its replacement `ZoneId` from *java.time*. Use only *java.time*; never use the terribly flawed legacy date-time classes.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.sytemDefault() ;
```

New conversion methods were added to the old classes for writing code to interoperate with old code not yet updated to java.time. TimeZone.getTimeZone( ZoneId ) is one such conversion method.

Also, be aware that the JVM’s current default time zone can be changed at any moment by any code in any thread. Consider if you really want your code to spin the wheel on time-zone-[roulette](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roulette) at runtime.

> `new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");`

Your formatting code uses `hh` in lowercase. This means 12-hour clock. But you neglected to collect an indicator of which half of the day. If the user types a time for `02:00:00`, we cannot know if they meant 2 AM or 2 PM. I will change this to `HH` for 24-hour clock in example code below.

> `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");`
> `Date date = sdf.parse(dateStr);`

Be aware that `SimpleDateFormat` is using a default time zone to parse that date-with-time string. You happen to want the default time zone in your earlier code, so this may work out well. Or this may not work out well if some code has changed your JVM’s current default time zone in the interim.

> `ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutorService.schedule(() -> System.out.println("alert!") , alertTimeInMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);`

This line is the source of your problem. You told the scheduled executor service to wait a number of milliseconds before executing. Your number of executors is the number of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC — decades, that is. You told the executor service to wait decades, about 53 years (2023-1970 = 53). Which the executor service will do, faithfully, if you leave your computer running that long.

Your code:

```
long alertTimeInMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

… calls the [`Calendar#getTimeInMillis`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis()) method. Javadoc says:

> Returns: the current time as UTC milliseconds from the epoch.

What you meant to do is what you *did* do in your `System.out.println`: Calculate time to elapse between the current moment and that target moment.

```
(alertTimeInMillis - now)
```

Tip: Generally best to log *existing* values, rather than *generating* a value to log.

## Modern solution: *java.time*

But enough of struggling with the terribly flawed legacy date-time classes. Never use `Calendar`, `Date`, or `SimpleDateFormat`. Always use *java.time* classes.

Firstly, if using an executor service, copy the boilerplate code for a graceful shutdown. Find that code on [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) Javadoc. Here is a slightly modified version.

```java
package work.basil.example.time;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class WaitToRunDemo
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        WaitToRunDemo app = new WaitToRunDemo();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
    }

    // My slightly modified version of boilerplate code taken from Javadoc of `ExecutorService`.
    // https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html 
    void shutdownAndAwaitTermination ( final ExecutorService executorService , final Duration waitForTasksToWork , final Duration waitForTasksToComplete )
    {
        executorService.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
        try
        {
            // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
            if ( ! executorService.awaitTermination( waitForTasksToWork.toMillis() , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS ) )
            {
                executorService.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
                // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
                if ( ! executorService.awaitTermination( waitForTasksToComplete.toMillis() , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS ) )
                { System.err.println( "ExecutorService did not terminate." ); }
            }
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException ex )
        {
            // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
            executorService.shutdownNow();
            // Preserve interrupt status
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is complete example code.

Let's break up your long code into a few separate methods, each with a specific goal.

To represent a span of time not attached to the timeline, use [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) class.

Notice how we minimized the use of `LocalDateTime`. That class cannot represent a moment, a point on the timeline as it lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. I cannot imagine a situation where calling `LocalDateTime.now` is optimal.

```java
package work.basil.example.time;

import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class WaitToRunDemo
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        WaitToRunDemo app = new WaitToRunDemo();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        ZonedDateTime then = this.gatherInput();
        Duration delayUntilTaskRuns = this.calculateTimeToElapse( then );
        System.out.println( "INFO - Now: " + Instant.now() + ". Scheduling task to run after delay of: " + delayUntilTaskRuns.toString() );

        this.runTask( delayUntilTaskRuns );
        System.out.println( "Demo done at " + Instant.now() );
    }

    private ZonedDateTime gatherInput ( )
    {
        // Put your `Scanner` code here. Tip: Confirm the time zone with the user.

        // Simulate the user entering text for the start of the next minute.
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();
        ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId );
        ZonedDateTime startOfNextMinute = now.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MINUTES ).plusMinutes( 1 );

        DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu HH:mm:ss" );
        String userInput = startOfNextMinute.format( f );
        System.out.println( "DEBUG startOfNextMinute = " + startOfNextMinute );
        System.out.println( "DEBUG userInput = " + userInput );

        // Parse user input text into a `LocalDateTime` object to represent date with time-of-day but lacking any time zone or offset-from-UTC. 
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( userInput , f );
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( zoneId );

        return zdt;
    }

    private Duration calculateTimeToElapse ( final ZonedDateTime then )
    {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        Duration delayUntilTaskRuns = Duration.between( now , then.toInstant() );
        if ( delayUntilTaskRuns.isNegative() ) { throw new IllegalStateException( "Specified wait time is negative (in the past)." ); }
        return delayUntilTaskRuns;
    }

    private void runTask ( Duration delay )
    {
        ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        Runnable task = ( ) -> System.out.println( "Done running task at " + Instant.now() );
        ses.schedule( task , delay.toMillis() , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
        this.shutdownAndAwaitTermination( ses , Duration.ofMinutes( 2 ) , Duration.ofMinutes( 1 ) );
    }

    // My slightly modified version of boilerplate code taken from Javadoc of `ExecutorService`.
    // https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html
    void shutdownAndAwaitTermination ( final ExecutorService executorService , final Duration waitForTasksToWork , final Duration waitForTasksToComplete )
    {
        executorService.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
        try
        {
            // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
            if ( ! executorService.awaitTermination( waitForTasksToWork.toMillis() , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS ) )
            {
                executorService.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
                // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
                if ( ! executorService.awaitTermination( waitForTasksToComplete.toMillis() , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS ) )
                { System.err.println( "ExecutorService did not terminate." ); }
            }
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException ex )
        {
            // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
            executorService.shutdownNow();
            // Preserve interrupt status
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Where run:

```
DEBUG startOfNextMinute = 2023-01-10T14:30-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
DEBUG userInput = 10-01-2023 14:30:00
INFO - Now: 2023-01-10T22:29:37.091459Z. Scheduling task to run after delay of: PT22.908594S
Done running task at 2023-01-10T22:30:00.012244Z
Demo done at 2023-01-10T22:30:00.024242Z
```

My example code when run was aiming to run the task at 2023-01-10T14:30-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]. That is the exact same moment, same point on the timeline as 2023-01-10T22:30:00Z where the “Z” means an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. The 14:30 in America/Los_Angeles is 8 hours behind UTC, so adding 8 hours brings us to 22:30 in UTC — same moment, different wall-clock time.

In other words… Alice in Portland Oregon notices her clock on the wall strike 2:30 PM (14:30) as she dials the phone to call Bob in [Reykjavík](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reykjav%C3%ADk). As Bob answers the call, he notices [his own clock on the wall](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Iceland) reads 10:30 PM (22:30). Same moment, different wall-clock time.

---

By the way, be aware that lines sent to `System.out.println` across threads may *not* appear in the console in chronological order. Always include a timestamp such as `Instant.now()`. If you care about sequence, study those timestamps.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer and teaching me out of scope like awaiting termination! Few questions: 1) You said it's weird I'm mixing legacy code with modern code, but `TimeZone#getTimeZone` accepts `ZoneId`, isn't it mixed by design then? 2) I'm confused about the prints, since the user input is `14:30` but it goes off at `22:30` your time. Is it a time zone issue? Thanks again!

Comment: @Nom1fan New conversion methods were added to the old classes for writing code to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*. `TimeZone.getTimeZone( ZoneId )` is one such conversion method.

Comment: My example code when run was aiming to run the task at 2023-01-10T14:30-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]. That is the exact same moment, same point on the timeline as 2023-01-10T22:30:00Z where the “Z” means an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. The 14:30 in `America/Los_Angeles` is 8 hours behind UTC, so adding 8 hours brings you to 22:30 in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

I modified Basil's modern answer slightly so the prints are on the same time zone and make more sense to me. Feel free to correct me if I've done something wrong.

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class WaitToRunDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WaitToRunDemo app = new WaitToRunDemo();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo() {
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();
        ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(zoneId);
        ZonedDateTime then = this.gatherInput(now, zoneId);
        Duration delayUntilTaskRuns = this.calculateTimeToElapse(now, then);
        System.out.println("INFO - Now: " + now + ". Scheduling task to run after delay of: " + delayUntilTaskRuns);

        this.runTask(delayUntilTaskRuns, zoneId);
        System.out.println("Demo done at: " + ZonedDateTime.now(zoneId));
    }

    private ZonedDateTime gatherInput(ZonedDateTime now, ZoneId zoneId) {
        // Put your `Scanner` code here. Tip: Confirm the time zone with the user.

        // Simulate the user entering text for the start of the next minute.
        ZonedDateTime startOfNextMinute = now.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES).plusMinutes(1);

        DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu HH:mm:ss");
        String userInput = startOfNextMinute.format(f);
        System.out.println("DEBUG startOfNextMinute = " + startOfNextMinute);
        System.out.println("DEBUG userInput = " + userInput);

        // Parse user input text into a `LocalDateTime` object to represent date with time-of-day but lacking any time zone or offset-from-UTC.
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(userInput, f);

        return ldt.atZone(zoneId);
    }

    private Duration calculateTimeToElapse(final ZonedDateTime now, final ZonedDateTime then) {
        Duration delayUntilTaskRuns = Duration.between(now, then);
        if (delayUntilTaskRuns.isNegative()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Specified wait time is negative (in the past).");
        }
        return delayUntilTaskRuns;
    }

    private void runTask(Duration delay, ZoneId zoneId) {
        ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        Runnable task = () -> System.out.println("Done running task at: " + ZonedDateTime.now(zoneId));
        ses.schedule(task, delay.toMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        this.shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ses, Duration.ofMinutes(2), Duration.ofMinutes(1));
    }

    // My slightly modified version of boilerplate code taken from Javadoc of `ExecutorService`.
    // https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html
    void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(final ExecutorService executorService, final Duration waitForTasksToWork, final Duration waitForTasksToComplete) {
        executorService.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
        try {
            // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
            if (!executorService.awaitTermination(waitForTasksToWork.toMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                executorService.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
                // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
                if (!executorService.awaitTermination(waitForTasksToComplete.toMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                    System.err.println("ExecutorService did not terminate.");
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
            executorService.shutdownNow();
            // Preserve interrupt status
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
DEBUG startOfNextMinute = 2023-01-11T10:55+02:00[Asia/Jerusalem]
DEBUG userInput = 11-01-2023 10:55:00
INFO - Now: 2023-01-11T10:54:45.494618+02:00[Asia/Jerusalem]. Scheduling task to run after delay of: PT14.505382S
Done running task at: 2023-01-11T10:55:00.036986+02:00[Asia/Jerusalem]
Demo done at: 2023-01-11T10:55:00.037542+02:00[Asia/Jerusalem]
```